# How to show a window with template from a url column in Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, templates, kendo-ui

I have a kendoGrid with a column that uses a command that looks like this:

```
command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }
```

The command calls the showDetails method which opens a kendoWindow:

```
function showDetails(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

This works as expected. Now I want to have another column that is a url that does the same thing when you click it. So far this is what I have for the template of that column:

```
template: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=showDetails>#=CourseTitle#</a>'
```

I basically followed the example from the Kendo website for the command: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command. The command has a click property, but the template does not and trying to set the onclick attribute of the url to the same value I use for the click property of the command doesn't work and I'm not sure how to modify this so that it works as I intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke function in onclick attribute you should use syntax with brackets:

```
<a onlick='functionName(this)'></a>
```

Then in you function you can get by parameter, the dom element which was click target.
So your template should looks like:

```
template: '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDetails(this)">#=CourseTitle#</a>'
```

You need to modify function showDetails like that:

```
function showDetails(e) {
    var dataItem, grid;
    if(e.currentTarget === undefined){
        grid = $(e).closest(".k-grid").data('kendoGrid');
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e).closest("tr"));
    }
    else{
        e.preventDefault()
        dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    }
    wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
    wnd.center().open();
}
```

Working Kendo UI Dojo example: http://dojo.telerik.com/ACozi